# Book where the main character lives in a sci-fi dystopia and is "sorted" and gets powers

Tags: story-identification, books, dystopia

The main character is male, everyone gets sorted/goes through some scanner thing and it's usually fine. For some reason his mom gets sorted red and I can't remember if she dies because of that? It might be like some sort of culling thing.

The world seems like pre-transformation *Pretties*/*Uglies*/*Specials* by Scott Westerfeld. Dirty and polluted.

I can't recall, but I think the light turns green for the main character. He is chosen to join the 1% and is transported to where the 1% live. They all have powers, which the main character is struggling to learn. There's a scene where he's struggling to lift/move a rock/boulder.

For some reason he travels back to the dystopia to visit and there's a scene where his lungs start burning and he doesn't remember it being so polluted. He also kisses the teacher girl who went with him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Do you remember the cover art or any of the character names?

Comment: (Thank you for the edit!) I don't recall the cover art being anything other than generic, it was red with the title on it. I read this about 6-4 years ago, and no, unfortunately :(

Comment: No problem!  We've answered questions with less than this before. :)  Is "sorted" the term used in the story?  Do you recall the word used or the name of the device?  Do they use the terms "powers" and "1%?"  Is there a literal red or green light?  (What is the result for people who are "fine?"  Nothing?  Yellow?)  When you say "teacher girl who went with him" do you refer to going through the device, joining the 1% or going back to the polluted world?  When did she join him?